# Connect to WiFi with WPS PIN, some questions

Tags: android, wifimanager, wps

I'm trying to make an App wich connect to a wifi with a known BSSID, ESSID and valid wps PIN.
I've looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719069/how-to-connect-with-wps-to-wifi-programmatically) but I don't understand it at all.
Wifi Manager has a method to connect by WPS with a config and a CallBack

```
mWifiManager.startWps(wpsConfig, mWpsCallback);
```

I understand what WpsCallBack does but... not how it works wpsConfig.
wpsConfig is a WpsInfo object, but I don't see how to set the BSSID and the PIN in order to connect to it.

Could someone give me a simple example or explanation?
I've looked into [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TvSettings/+/lollipop-wear-release/Settings/src/com/android/tv/settings/connectivity/WpsConnectionActivity.java), but I don't see what I'm looking for...

Thanks!

P.D: My project minSdk is 21.